# Data comparison to workflow state

Tags: rules, 9

I am using the workflow module paired with rules.   The current issue I'm struggling with is getting the reaction rule condition set up properly to only send an email to users of role when the workflow state is Dean Approval.

The export of the rule as I currently have it set up is as follows.

```yaml
uuid: 13d6007f-b0a6-420c-936a-00be67b1e7aa
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: after_saving_workflow_transition
label: 'After Saving Workflow Transition'
events:
  -
    event_name: 'rules_entity_insert:workflow_transition--npd'
description: ''
tags: {  }
config_version: '3'
expression:
  id: rules_rule
  uuid: 55ce8559-dc07-4544-864a-9ac4dcca7da2
  weight: 0
  conditions:
    id: rules_and
    uuid: 8b073ce4-3994-4c4e-8a75-2f58e52181b3
    weight: 0
    conditions:
      -
        id: rules_condition
        uuid: f8c68976-79e4-4a2a-81b0-abce71f14bf0
        weight: 0
        condition_id: rules_entity_is_of_bundle
        negate: true
        context_values:
          type: node
          bundle: proposal
        context_mapping:
          entity: workflow_transition
        context_processors:
          type:
            rules_tokens: {  }
          bundle:
            rules_tokens: {  }
        provides_mapping: {  }
      -
        id: rules_condition
        uuid: 7a3bfad3-da0c-4a05-99be-5c571d9f13df
        weight: 0
        condition_id: rules_data_comparison
        negate: false
        context_values:
          operation: CONTAINS
          value: 'Dean Approval'
        context_mapping:
          data: workflow_transition
        context_processors:
          operation:
            rules_tokens: {  }
          value:
            rules_tokens: {  }
        provides_mapping: {  }
  actions:
    id: rules_action_set
    uuid: a9a136ba-9416-48a3-a309-55172d1c79dd
    weight: 0
    actions:
      -
        id: rules_action
        uuid: c3ef0fee-1405-4d81-8cb6-1282ab32d9da
        weight: 0
        action_id: rules_email_to_users_of_role
        context_values:
          roles:
            - Administrator
          subject: Test
          message: 'email to users of a role test'
          reply: donotreply@example.com
          language: ''
        context_mapping: {  }
        context_processors:
          roles:
            rules_tokens: {  }
          subject:
            rules_tokens: {  }
          message:
            rules_tokens: {  }
          reply:
            rules_tokens: {  }
          language:
            rules_tokens: {  }
        provides_mapping: {  }
```

Without the Dean Approval condition the email fires, but with it, it doesn't, so I know I'm not setting this up correctly, I'm just not seeing what I'm doing wrong.   If I try to dig down into workflow_transition (ie: workflow_transition.to_sid.entity) I get a WSOD.

> InvalidArgumentException: Value is not a valid entity. in Drupal\Core\Entity\Plugin\DataType\EntityReference->setValue() (line 106 of /var/www/app/npd_davenport.edu_test_build22/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Plugin/DataType/EntityReference.php).`

I am using Rules version 8.x-3.0-alpha7 on Drupal 9.4.5.

Comment: I think the value your comparing against in your condition probably needs to be the machine name of the workflow state, not the label. Something like `dean_approval`, maybe? You could find the machine name in your workflow's settings.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @sonfd, changing to the machine name of the state didn't change the outcome.